# I dont understand my own code

Tags: c#

Lets say that the user wants to calculate the multiplication table of any number, up to any line they want. So the user inputs in 2 and then he inputs in 10. The console writes out everything multiple up to ten. My code does that but I don't understand why I have to set my `int counter = -1`, instead of `0`.

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("The number of lines you want to calculate up to ");
    int loops = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    if (loops <0)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Can not enter a value less then zero... Try Again?");
         Console.ReadLine();
         goto Start;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("What multiplication tables would you like to do ?");
    int m = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int counter = -1; counter <= loops; counter+=1)
    {
        for (int mt = m; mt >= 0; mt += m)
        {
            if (mt % m == 0)
            {
                counter += 1;
                if (counter == loops)
                {
                    break;
                }                            
            }                                                
            Console.WriteLine(mt);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers only");
    Console.ReadLine();
    goto Start;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. much less the code. Could you show what output you expect if 2 and 10 are entered?

Comment: The title made me rofl, seriously

Comment: Step through your code until you figure it out.

Comment: Create your own example for loops and m and write out all of the values you get for loops, m, mt, and counter. Pay close attention to counter because I think that might be where your issue lies -- since you are incrementing counter in both of your for loops. BTW, the common way to increment by one is counter++ instead of counter += 1. EG: for (counter = 0; counter < loops; counter++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your incrementing before you check the counter which is why you have to start the counter at -1.

```
  if (counter == loops)
  {
       break;
  }     
  counter += 1; //move below the if statement
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do. Does this work?

```
try
{
        Console.WriteLine("The number of lines you want to calculate up to");
        int loops = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

        if (loops < 0)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Can not enter a value less then zero... Try Again?");
             Console.ReadLine();
             goto Start;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("What multiplication tables would you like to do ?");

        int m = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 1; i <= loops; i++)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(i * m); 
        }    
}

catch
{
        Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers only");
        Console.ReadLine();
        goto Start;
}
```